# How to determine whether View state is being restored

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-lifecycle

In my custom view i have some field that I want to restore or create new instance if it will not be restored. Surprisingly I didn't find answer for that

Examle class

```
class MyView extends View {
    private Calendar calendar;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(!restoring())
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("state", super.onSaveInstanceState());
        b.putLong("calendar", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (state instanceof Bundle) {
            Bundle b = ((Bundle) state);
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(b.getParcelable("state"));
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(b.getLong("calendar"));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some check inside custom view that I can make to determine whether view will be restored?

In `Activity` there is `Bundle savedInstanceState` passed to `onCreate()`

I thought of making static boolean but it is not way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some check inside custom view that I can make to determine whether view will be restored?

Within `View` class there does **not** exist such an API.

The only seam that is given you is [`onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)), which will *"never be called with `null` state"*. Thus, if you end up being in `onRestoreInstanceState()`, then you can assume, that the view is being restored. Otherwise it is **not**.

Comment: Ok, thats unfortunate because I will have to restructure my logic. Thanks for clarification